# How to load a remote JavaScript file in a JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm trying to execute some Scripts from a remote API.
When i'm uploading to my server, the `.js` won't execute.Although in `localhost` they work just fine.

This is my JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="client.Errors"%>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      <title>Phill Login-In</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function formSubmit(form) {
             setTimeout(function () {
                 form.submit();
             },
             3000);// 3 seconds
             return false;
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <%
      String reqId = request.getParameter("request_id");       
      %>
   <body>
      <form name="phillLogin" id="formData" action="/oam/server/auth_cred_submit" method="POST" onsubmit="return formSubmit(this);">
         <div class='login'>
            <div class='login_title'>
               <%String err = request.getParameter("p_error_code");%>
               <%if (err==null){%>
               <h3>
                  <b>Login to your account</b>
               </h3>
               <% }%>
               <%if(err!=null)
                  {
                     Errors errors=new Errors();
                     Object simpleMessage[][]=(Object[][])errors.getContents(); 
                     String temp[]=err.split("-");
                     int pos=Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
                  %>
               <h3>
                  <%=simpleMessage[pos-1][1].toString()%>
               </h3>
               <%}%>
            </div>
            <div class='login_fields'>
               <div class='login_fields__user'>
                  <div class='icon'>
                     <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/user_icon_copy.png'/>
                  </div>
                  <input placeholder='Username' type="text" name="username" id="user" style="font-size:medium;"/>
                  <div class='validation'>
                     <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/tick.png'/>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class='login_fields__password'>
                  <div class='icon'>
                     <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/lock_icon_copy.png'/>
                  </div>
                  <input placeholder='Password' type="password" name="password" id="pass"
                     style="font-size:medium;"/>
                  <div class='validation'>
                     <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/tick.png'/>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class='login_fields__submit'>
                  <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="Submit" style="font-size:small;"/>
               </div>
            </div>
            <%
               if(reqId != null && reqId.length() > 0) { %>
            <input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="=reqId%>"/>
            <% } %>
         </div>
      </form>
      <div class='authent'>
         <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/puff.svg' />
         <p>Proccessing Data...</p>
      </div>
      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
      <script src="./script.js"></script>
      <script></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

> Note that these are the scripts that can't be accessed remotely from the server

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

**How can  i properly load these scripts to my file?**

I've tried includng the following inside `<head>` but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
   (function (d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {
         return;
     }
     js = d.createElement(s);
     js.id = id;
     js.onload = function () {
         // remote script has loaded
     };
     js.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }
   (document, 'script', 'first'));
</script>
<script>
   (function (d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {
         return;
     }
     js = d.createElement(s);
     js.id = id;
     js.onload = function () {
         // remote script has loaded
     };
     js.src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }
   (document, 'script', 'first'));
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried to look in the console for errors then google them ?

Comment: i don't get any kind of error in the `logs`. they just don't load. Did you read what i wrote?

Comment: what logs man in the console, do you got errors in the browser  **console**?

Comment: Is remote page on `https` protocol? Note that browser console and server logs are not same thing. Check js errors in browser dev tools console

Comment: Did you say that putting your script inside the HEAD tag didn't work? That is really strange. Did you try an alert('HI!'); inside the script? That SHOULD work.

Comment: @charlietfl, yes , i replaced it with `https` is that enough?(it runs perfectly on `localhost` )
@ErwinMoller yes , they work.

Comment: "Note that these are the scripts that can't be accessed remotely from the server" — They don't need to be accessed from the server, they need to be accessed from the browser. If they don't work, then you presumably have a firewall blocking them and should find alternative URLs or fix the firewall.

Comment: `jquery/2.1.3` — **Danger**: jQuery 2.x is unsupported and no longer receives security updates. Migrate to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: @Quentin is there any way to "`load`" them in my remote server?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis — First you need to determine why they aren't loading. Use the debugging tools in the browser. Look at the Network tab to check the requests and responses for the JS. Look at the Console for errors.

Comment: @Quentin they are... on localhost

Comment: @PhillAlexakis – Then you need to do your debugging on the server where they don't work.

Comment: @Quentin i'm in server logs, but no exception is being triggered

Comment: @PhillAlexakis — So try following the advice I gave in my earlier comment and debug from the other end.

Comment: @Quentin okay but , shouldn't `jquery/1.11.2` work?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis — Well, since you're now mixing up jQuery and jQuery UI URLs … possibly not … but other that that, and all else being equal — yes. But you said it doesn't work so clearly all else is **not** equal … so you need to debug it!

Comment: The remote cdn files never even see your server so checking logs there is useless. Note you can use protocol relative urls so they woudn't need to be changed for different protocols

Comment: @Quentin you are right, jQuery 3.x works perfectly, i used both scripts from `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` and now it works perfect from the remote server

Comment: @Quentin these are the scripts i used `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` **and this** `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-KM512VNnjElC30ehFwehXjx1YCHPiQkOPmqnrWtpccM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: @Quentin u can post it as an answer if you want to